# Move a point toward the mouse

Tags: java, math, processing

[image]

(I'm using processing for this but it is not necessarily relevant.)

> I'm looking for an algorithm that would take the point A and the point B (B being the mouse cursor position) and use them so that every frame the point A moves a little bit towards B (from -1px to 1px left/right up/down)

I tried **x1 += cos(atan((mouseY-y1)/(mouseX-x1)))** and the same with sin for y1, but I doesn't seem to work.

If someone has an idea I would appreciate it.

I'm *not* looking for a built-in function that would do the job, I'd like to understand the math behind it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are `x1` and `y1` floating point or ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important that the point coordinates are floating point values:

```java
float x = 0.0, y= 0.0;
```

For the computation of the movement of the point, I recommend to use [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html).

Setup 2 vectors, for the point and the mouse position:

```java
PVector Pt = new PVector(x, y);
PVector Pm = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);
```

Calculate the [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) from `Pt` to `Pm`:

```java
PVector D = PVector.sub(Pm, Pt);
D.normalize();
```

Calculate the new point by `newPt = Pt + D * min(speed, dist)`, but ensure that the point moves not further than the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to the mouse:

```java
float speed = 3;
float movelen = min(PVector.dist(Pt, Pm), speed);
PVector newPt = PVector.add(Pt, D.mult(movelen));
```

The same can be achieved by arithmetic operations

```java
float dx = mouseX - x;
float dy = mouseY - y;
float dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
if (dist > 0) {
    float movelen = min(dist, speed);
    x += dx/dist * movelen;
    y += dy/dist * movelen;
}
```

(`dx`,`dy`) is the vector from the point to the mouse and `dist` ist the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the 2 points. A [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) can be calculated by dividing a vector by its magnitude, so (`dx/dist`, `dy/dist`) is the unit direction vector.
Finally (`dx/dist * movelen`, `dx/dist * movelen`) is the same as `D * movelen`.

See the example:
(the code works for any `speed`, even below 1.0)

[image]

```java
float x = 0.0, y= 0.0;

void setup() {
    size(300, 300);
    x = (float)random(width);
    y = (float)random(height);
}

void draw() {
    float speed = 3;

    /*
    //setup points
    PVector Pt = new PVector(x, y);
    PVector Pm = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);

    // calcualte normalized direction
    PVector D = PVector.sub(Pm, Pt);
    D.normalize();

    // calcualte new point
    float movelen = min(PVector.dist(Pt, Pm), speed);
    PVector newPt = PVector.add(Pt, D.mult(movelen));
    x = newPt.x;
    y = newPt.y;
    */

    float dx = mouseX - x;
    float dy = mouseY - y;
    float dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    if (dist > 0) {
        float movelen = min(dist, speed);
        x += dx/dist * movelen;
        y += dy/dist * movelen;
    }

    background(196);
    stroke(0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse((int)x, (int)y, 10, 10);
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer that show both ways (with vector and without), i'm gonna stick with the version without the vectors because i'm not familiar enough with them. I have a little bit of trouble understanding the part in the if(dist>0), movelen chose the lowest value between the distance and the speed, what does "dx * movelen / dist" do? Thanks!

Comment: @user3144480 (`dx`, `dy`) is the vector from the point to the mouse. `dist` ist the Euclidean distance and (`dx/dist`, `dy/dist`) is the unit direction vector. So (`dx/dist * movelen`, `dx/dist * movelen`) is the same as `D * min(speed, dist)`

Comment: I could watch that animation for hours